# ESLint - How to enforce only typescript files (*.ts, *.tsx) can be added to a project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

We are migrating our React codebase to Typescript gradually. I'd like to add a rule to our eslint config to ensure all the new files that are going to be created have only `*.ts` or `*.tsx` extension. I can add the current list of `*.js` and `*.jsx` files as an ignore list to this rule.

Is there such a rule? I found https://github.com/dolsem/eslint-plugin-filename-rules but this seems more about file name pattern rather than the extension.

Comment: The custom regex option for that rule seems like it would work – did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this simple script to achieve it:

```
find . -name '*.js' -o -name '*.jsx' | (! grep -vFf existing_js_files.txt )
```

Comment: Awesome! Was gonna suggest to think out of the box and write a small script, but you did it.